# "Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'" - PHP+CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá, tenho as seguintes tabelas no banco de dados:

- dados_vaga aonde a mesma posssui vários campos e um dos mesmos é id_vaga, id_academico.
- dados_candidato aonde a mesma possui vários campos e um é o seguinte id_vaga.

Quando eu salvo uma vaga a mesma tem o id_vaga, que futuramente quando uma pessoa vai se cadastrar na vaga(tabela dados_candidato) salva na mesma o id_vaga e o id_academico referente a vaga e ao usuario em questão.

So que vai acontecer de um candidato ter várias vagas a que o mesmo se candidatou, como eu faço para listar aquelas vagas? 
So que como há vários id_vaga referente ao mesmo candidato eu não sei como passar os mesmos para a query. 
Eu tentei fazer o seguinte:

```
  function getMinhasVagas($id_academico){
  $id_academico = $this->session->userdata('id_academico');
  $this->db
          ->select("id_vaga")
          ->from("dados_candidato")
          ->where('id_academico', $id_academico );


    $qr = $this->db->get()->result();

    $this->db->select("*")->from("dados_vaga")->where('id_vaga', $qr);
    return $teste = $this->db->get()->result();

}
```

Retorna o seguinte erro: **Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'.**

Obrigado a quem me responder, tenham um bom dia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tentou jogar no valor do where um array($qr), o que seria uma espécie de "IN".

Com base no que você falou eu entendi a seguinte estrutura:

**dados_vaga**

- id_vaga
- id_academico

**dados_candidato**

- id_vaga

Eu resolveria isso com um select apenas:

```
return $this->db->query("SELECT dv.*
                        FROM dados_vaga dv
                        INNER JOIN dados_candidato dc on dc.id_vaga = dv.id_vaga
                        WHERE dv.id_academico = ?", array($id_academico)
                       )->result();
```

ou

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('dados_vaga');
$this->db->join('dados_candidato', 'dados_candidato.id_vaga = dados_vaga.id_vaga');
$this->db->where("dados_vagas.id_academico", $id_academico);
return $this->db->get()->result();
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer algo dessa maneira para acessar a propriedade que você precisa:

```
$this->db->select("*")->from("dados_vaga")->where('id_vaga', $qr->id_vaga);
```

Comment: Não sei se eu entendi errado, mas $qr pode ter vários resultados, para poder acessar $qr->id_vaga, ele tinha que ter usado row(). Acho que está errado. Caso eu estiver enganado me desculpe.

Comment: @Murilo Você tem razão, deve usar row() antes para que consiga acessar a propriedade do registro. Entretanto, creio que ele queira somente o primeiro resultado, já que ele busca por um ``id`` específico da vaga.